# Laptop idle power consumption tuning when using Yubikey Nano

Tags: usb, system, power-management, pci, yubico

**Background**

About a year ago, I used powertop to optimise my laptop's power consuption (following [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Powertop#Usage) and [this](https://www.kuketz-blog.de/gnu-linux-notebook-power-saving-mit-powertop/) guide), ending up with this systemd service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Powertop tunings for X1 Carbon 5th

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "echo '1500' > '/proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs';"
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "echo '1' > '/sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save';"
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "echo '0' > '/proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog';"
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-0/device/power/control';"
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-2/device/power/control';"
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-9/power/control';"
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-1/device/power/control';"
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:00.0/power/control';"
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.2/power/control';"
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:08.0/power/control';"
# ... omitted some more PCI devices ...

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Problem analysis**

This worked fine and brought my laptop's idle power consumption down - until a few months ago when I got a Yubikey 5C nano.

Now however, my laptop's idle power consumption rose from previous 5-5.5W to now 5.8-6.2W (without Yubikey Nano plugged versus plugged in. Readings observed on a idle system with no open programs over 5ish minutes.)

It's not the Yubikey that's consuming this extra watt, otherwise it would likely be [on fire](https://forum.yubico.com/viewtopic64df.html?p=8668). Instead it's probably caused by the USB controllers not going to sleep as they should.

When I run `powertop` I get the following in the *Tuning* tab:

```
| Description | Script |
| ----------- | ------ |
| Autosuspend for USB device YubiKey OTP+FIDO+CCID [Yubico] | echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/usb/devices/3-2/power/control'; |
| Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] | echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:3c:00.0/power/control'; |
| Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] | echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:07:04.0/power/control'; |
| Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] | echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:07:01.0/power/control'; |
```

However, if I remove the Yubikey, insert it again, and run `powertop --html=reportB.html` again I get the following in the *Tuning* tab:

```
| Description | Script |
| ----------- | ------ |
| Autosuspend for USB device YubiKey OTP+FIDO+CCID [Yubico] | echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/usb/devices/3-2/power/control'; |
| Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] | echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:3c:00.0/power/control'; |
| Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] | echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:07:02.0/power/control'; |
| Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] | echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:06:00.0/power/control'; |
| Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] | echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:07:04.0/power/control'; |
| Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] | echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:07:01.0/power/control'; |
```

**Question**

This leads me to a series of question:

1. Am I right in understanding that every time you plug in a USB device - even if it's been plugged in before - it will be assigned a new PCI identifier?
2. Is it wise to add these tuning commands to my systemd service?

   - What are the possible side effects?
   - What about only the `Autosuspend for USB device YubiKey`?
3. Would it be wise to add all commands given the constraint that I will never actually remove the Yubikey from its USB port? (*)

   - What would then be the implications if in some odd circumstance I were to remove it anyway?

Thanks a lot!

(*) That is the whole point of having the Nano, being too lazy to always use the big Yubikey.